How do you compile OpenCV with Python with CUDA Support on Rocky Linux 9?
I am trying to build opencv-python per the official instructions with support for CUDA so I can run SIFT. When I try to build with pip wheel . --verbose I get:
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hrc4y4f6/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 664, in setup
      env = cmkr.configure(
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hrc4y4f6/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 354, in configure
      raise SKBuildError(msg)

  An error occurred while configuring with CMake.
    Command:
      /tmp/pip-build-env-hrc4y4f6/overlay/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake /home/grant/chinese_test/opencv-python/opencv -G 'Unix Makefiles' --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/home/grant/chinese_test/opencv-python/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.9/cmake-install -DPYTHON_VERSION_STRING:STRING=3.9.18 -DSKBUILD:INTERNAL=TRUE -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH:PATH=/tmp/pip-build-env-hrc4y4f6/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skbuild/resources/cmake -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:PATH=/usr/bin/python3 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/python3.9 -DPYTHON_LIBRARY:PATH=/usr/lib64/libpython3.9.so -DPython_EXECUTABLE:PATH=/usr/bin/python3 -DPython_ROOT_DIR:PATH=/usr -DPython_FIND_REGISTRY:STRING=NEVER -DPython_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/python3.9 -DPython_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=/tmp/pip-build-env-hrc4y4f6/overlay/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/_core/include -DPython3_EXECUTABLE:PATH=/usr/bin/python3 -DPython3_ROOT_DIR:PATH=/usr -DPython3_FIND_REGISTRY:STRING=NEVER -DPython3_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/python3.9 -DPython3_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=/tmp/pip-build-env-hrc4y4f6/overlay/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/_core/include -DWITH_CUDA=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 -DCUDA_FAST_MATH=1 -DWITH_CUBLAS=1 -DOPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON -DPYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 -DPYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 -DPYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.9 -DPYTHON3_LIBRARY=/usr/lib64/libpython3.9.so -DBUILD_opencv_python3=ON -DBUILD_opencv_python2=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_java=OFF -DOPENCV_PYTHON3_INSTALL_PATH=python -DINSTALL_CREATE_DISTRIB=ON -DBUILD_opencv_apps=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_freetype=OFF -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_DOCS=OFF -DPYTHON3_LIMITED_API=ON -DBUILD_OPENEXR=ON -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/grant/chinese_test/opencv-python/opencv_contrib/modules -DWITH_CUDA=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 -DCUDA_FAST_MATH=1 -DWITH_CUBLAS=1 -DOPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON
    Source directory:
      /home/grant/chinese_test/opencv-python/opencv
    Working directory:
      /home/grant/chinese_test/opencv-python/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.9/cmake-build
  Please see CMake's output for more information.

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for opencv-contrib-python (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  full command: /usr/bin/python3 /home/grant/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpzppm94gi
  cwd: /home/grant/chinese_test/opencv-python
  Building wheel for opencv-contrib-python (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-contrib-python
Failed to build opencv-contrib-python
ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels

I searched for output recursively in the directory tree and there was nothing related to cmake's output so I don't know where it is putting that.
I have done this:

Clone this repository: git clone --recursive https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python.git
cd opencv-python
The below flags:

export CMAKE_ARGS="-DWITH_CUDA=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 -DCUDA_FAST_MATH=1 -DWITH_CUBLAS=1 -DOPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON"
export ENABLE_CONTRIB=1
pip wheel . --verbose


Can you show the cmake output please?

It says that, but when I searched the directory recursively for case insensitive output there was no such file.

I reproduced it from a CUDA vanilla container. I got this log https://pastebin.com/a5aUmYc5 if it can helps. It has many error related that I did not install all the CUDA toolkit (the image does not have the complete suite I think?), I might miss CUBLAS or some env variable to expose it.  Also I miss ninja, I installed it and it does not fix the build. Also you can delete the _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.10/cmake-build/CMakeCache.txt to have more verbose? I have no idea why you do not have any log comparable to mine.
